# One additional day of the year in order to faciliate present dispersal by Santa Claus

Tags: santa-claus, conspiracy

In my world, Santa Claus is the head of a large, super-secret organization that employs a large army of paramilitarily organized elves to disperse presents at Christmas, utilizing automated factories and transportation technology received from the Grays and Reptilian Aliens.

However, it still takes twenty-four hours to faciliate the dispersal of Christmas presents to the two billion people who celebrate the holiday worldwide. As such, a day has to be added to the year. 24 hours, in which only the elves and the military are awake and everybody else is kept in an artificial comatose sleep.

Precisely, one day is *stolen* from the year (which is actually 366 or (if a gap uear) 367 days long).

This implies lots of problems. Here are the main ones:

- How can the evidence for a “stolen day” be hidden? How can reputable astronomers or scientists be prevented from unmasking the lie using simple observations and calculations? It is okay if conspiracy theorists can try to “spread the truth”, but normal people should not be compelled to track the sun’s location and calculate the Earth’s orbital period from that by themselves instead of using the (fake) numbers provided by the government.
- How can a smooth “phase-in” and/or “phase-out” be guaranteed so that those who awaken early do not notice that the rest of the world is still asleep?

The following limitations shall encourage creative thinking:

- No time travel or physics bending.
- Please keep mind control or memory wiping to a minimum. It is mandatory for those not involved in the operation to be in an artificial coma during the time period, and there will probably be lots of disinformation and psychotronics used, but please, please try to minimize such techniques used. They will be discussed in a separate question.

It can be assumed that the organization performing the operation consists of several dozens of millions of people (with minimal whistleblowing activity) that work fully cooperatively and efficiently.

Note: this does NOT deal with the means by which the population is brought into a comatose state.

Comment: This question deals with the astronomical/physical implications, the other one with how to bring the humans into the comatose state.

Comment: "Several dozen million people" and "minimal whistleblowing activity" seem rather mutually exclusive. There were a double-digit number of people involved in Watergate, for instance, but still one of them spilled the beans.

Comment: Quite frankly I'd love to ban Santa Claus questions in the same way that, as a believer in the "conspiracy" that Big Business has taken over Christmas, I'm against the whole mess now.  Please join me in shooting down Santa Clauses wherever you see them (you may fondle your weapons now).  Bonus points for not hurting the deer (except that snooty red nosed bar-steward - you can nail him if you want - can't stand show offs). :-)

Comment: I'm not going to VTC this question, but I am going to downvote it because I believe it's fundamentally unanswerable.  On Dec 31 the star positions were recorded.  On Dec 32 Santa does his thing.  On Jan 1 everybody looks at the data and tries to make the math work because for whatever concocted reason they don't think Dec 32 existed.  I don't think there's a suspension-of-disbelief condition that allows that to ever work.  See the STNG episode "[Clues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clues_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation))" for the basis of your problem.

Comment: Why would you need an additional day? There are time zones; midnight in Tokyo is about 12 hours away from midnight in London, for instance.

Comment: Astronomers will notice if Earth seems to jump 1 day's travel farther in its orbit.  Timing of the orbits of the Galilean moons of Jupiter was once used to determine longitude.  Astronomers will notice if those moon jump a day forward in their orbits.  Radio astronomers will notice that the steadily lengthening periods of pulsars have all jumped a day.  People will notice that animals and plants have grown a lot more than expected, especially in the southern hemisphere where Xmas in in the summer. People who have to take medicine periodically will suffer, and some may die as a result.

Answer (score 2):

The problem to be solved is more a failure of logic than the necessity for adding an additional but deeply secret day to the calendar to facilitate the delivery of toys and presents by Santa Claus and his paramilitary elves.

Remember the planet turns on its axis, and takes twenty-four hours to do so, this means any single moment of the clock will last for a full twenty-four hours. For example, 1 am an Xmas Day, it will be 1 am somewhere in the world for 24 hours. of course, this will be sequential as the planet rotates.

Assume the present delivery takes place at 1 am, as was assumed above, then around the world it will be 1 am, effectively, for the next 24 hours. This is sufficient time for alien transportation technology to deliver presents (which is one of the basic assumptions of the question).

In conclusion, the world's two billion children will receive their presents, in a timely manner, because it takes the Earth twenty-four hours to pass through any time zone, which is exactly the amount of time needed the delivery of those presents via alien transportation technology. No additional but totally secret day in the calendar is required to carry out this beneficent task. The calendar will still only have 365.25 days in the year (with corrections every leap year).